# Power BI DAX - Dynamically Categorize Column Values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column of the form

```
  Revenue
    10000
    20000
      500
        1
     3300
      800
       90
       45
      200
       55
```

I would like to create a new column in my power bi dataset that dynamically buckets these into Top  20%, Top 20-50%, Bottom 20-50% and Bottom 20% revenue contribution based on the range of values in the column .

How do I achieve this with DAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your difference is between Top and Bottom 20-50%. I assume there's a typo.

I'm pretty new to DAX, and I'm not sure if this is exactly how you want to bucket the values, but it seems you could do this with `RANKX` and a nested `IF` formula:

```
Rank =
IF (
    RANKX ( 'Table', [Revenue], [Revenue], ASC )
        >= ( 0.8 * COUNT ( 'Table'[Revenue] ) ),
    "Top 20%",
    IF (
        RANKX ( 'Table', [Revenue], [Revenue], ASC )
            >= ( 0.5 * COUNT ( 'Table'[Revenue] ) ),
        "Top 50%-80%",
        IF (
            RANKX ( 'Table', [Revenue], [Revenue], ASC )
                >= ( 0.2 * COUNT ( 'Table'[Revenue] ) ),
            "Bottom 20-50%",
            "Bottom 20%"
        )
    )
)
```

*I sorted the output to make results easier to see*
[image]

If you want to bucket using some other algorithm, please clarify.

Comment: This works for my needs. Thank you